# My Google Apps Script doesn't work and I don't know why

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm a newcomer to this site and I have a few questions:

I want to make a time recorder, for which someone will input any data in a Google Sheet ( a cell any place)

My code works successfully, but I can't see any results from my spreadsheets.

Here is my code:

```
    function endofstudy(e) {
        var app = SpreadsheetApp;
        var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
        var currentCell = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("sheetname!K1255:K2000")
         if( currentCell.getRange < "101" ) { 
          var nextCell = currentCell.offset(0, -9);
          var newDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"GMT+09:00", "HH:mm");
          nextCell.setValue(newDate);
        }
      }
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In your script, how do you run your script? I cannot understand `I want to make some time recorder, which is that someone input any data in google spreadsheets, and next cell, or furthermore another place` and `my code works successfully, but i can't find any results from my spreadsheets`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: that means if someone input data in cell A1, then google apps script records the time that someone input data in cell A1 in cell C1. sorry for my bad english

Comment: i want to make timestamp which works in my spreadsheet. i don't know the word "timestamp"

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that your question has been resolved. I'm glad for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you describe is typically called `onEdit` and is a simple trigger that doesn't need to be installed.  Your function `endofstudy` need to be installed through the script editor.

I've shown an `onEdit(e)` that uses the event object to tell which cell is being edited and how to offset from there to place a time stamp.

I've edited my script to address the comments below.

**Code.gs**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if( e.range.getSheet().getName() === "Sheet1" ) {  // limit this onEdit to only Sheet1
    if( e.range.getColumn() === 11 ) {  // Limit to only column K
      let row = e.range.getRow();
      if( ( row >= 1255 ) && ( row <= 2000 ) ) {  // Limit to rows 1255 to 2000
        let now = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"GMT+09:00", "HH:mm");
        e.range.offset(0,-7).setValue(now);  // offset -7 columns (K to D) from the cell being edited
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Reference**

- [Simple Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)
- [Event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [Range.offset()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset)
- [Range.setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)

Comment: really thank you!! but when i use it, my google apps script doesn't know where the range is. it said that  Cannot read property 'range' of undefined..

Comment: You can not run this from the script editor.  When the user edits a cell in the spreadsheet and hits enter the `onEdit(e)` trigger is fired with `e` containing the range and value that was edited.

Comment: and i want to work my timestamp while someone write string, and in that case, how can i use my code?

Comment: You can not use your current code.  There are too many errors in it.  It is really unclear from your code what you are trying to do.

Comment: Did you mean to limit the edit to column K?  If someone changes a value in column  K from row 1255 to 2000 then add a time stamp in column B (-9) of that row?  Because you mentioned A and C in your OP.

Comment: i don't use my code anymore. i just want to make simple time stamp by editing a cell(not only numbers, but also strings)

Comment: yes, That's what i want to make. i just make time stamp code that someone input data in column K, and time stamps in column D...

Comment: I've updated my script to address your comments